# Filtering out ".onmicrosoft.com" adresses from ProxyAdresses - Get-AzureADUser

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I was wondering if there is a way to filter the result under ***proxyadresses*** when i run:

```
$Users = Get-AzureADUser -All:$true | Select-Object DisplayName, mail, @{n="ProxyAddresses";e={$_.ProxyAddresses -join "`r`n"}}
```

The result of that would be *kinda* like this atm..

```
DisplayName        Mail                    ProxyAddresses
-----------        ----                    --------------
name1              name1@email.com         smtp:name1@email.com
name2              name2@email.com         SMTP:name2@email.com, SMTP:admin@email.com, smtp:name2@email.com.onmicrosoft.com...
name3              name3@email.com         smtp:name@email.com.onmicrosoft.com...
```

and im plotting this into a html table in hudu after. atm this works fine. but i would like it if there was a way to exclude the "onmicrosoft" adress from there. i dont want to use
`| Where-Object { $_.ProxyAddresses -notmatch "onmicrosoft" }`
because that would just remove every user that in an alias.

could it be possible to just do a `-replace` somehow, and then replace it with an empty string?

I would be super happy for any help with this! :)

Comment: `@{n="ProxyAddresses";e={($_.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'onmicrosoft'}) -join "`r`n"}}`

Comment: @Theo Thanku kind person!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank You [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) for providing your suggestion. Converting it to as an answer to help other community member.

```
$Users = Get-AzureADUser -All:$true | Select-Object DisplayName, mail, @{n="ProxyAddresses";e={$_.ProxyAddresses -join "`r`n"}}
```

[image]

Replace with below code for getting the user excluding `.onmicrosoft.com`

```
$Users = Get-AzureADUser -All:$true | Select-Object DisplayName, mail, @{n="ProxyAddresses";e={($_.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'onmicrosoft'}) -join "rn"}}
```

[image]

Comment: You took someone's comment and copied it as your own answer. This is plagiarism. Next time, as the commenter to post as an answer, if you feel it's right as an answer. But... don't just take someone else's work and post it as your own. This does not help community members when they see someone else's content copied.